# Does AVL tree left node is always smaller than current node?

Tags: tree, avl-tree

The definition of AVL tree is "keep Balance Factor smaller than 1".
(and definition of balance factor is |left child height-right child height| )

there is no condition need to all left childs are smaller than current Node, and all right childs are bigger than current node.

But, every example about AVL tree in wikipedia and some youtube video shows "left childs are~ and right childs~bigger".

why? Just coincidence? or AVL tree need "left~and right~"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it.

Because it is "search" tree, so when I insert item as a anode, it have to follow the rule "left thing is smaller". through root to leaf.